# How to derive field modulation from atom with given atom density matrix?

Tags: atomic-physics

As a two-level atom evolves in accordance with the Optical Bloch Equations in a laser field, how do I calculate the change of the field evolution due to the fact that atom absorbs and emits photons?

Comment: Please don't use undefined and obscure acronyms.  I've been in optical / solid state physics for 40 years and I don't know what OBE means.

Comment: Sorry! For clarifications, OBE: Optical Bloch equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to derive the equation(s) within the cavity quantum electrodynamics formalism, where you *quantise* the electric field. Otherwise, the usual optical Bloch equation is a semi-classical approach which assumes the electric field is a continuum.

It's actually all on the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Bloch_equations), where at the end they re-write the (Maxwell-)Bloch equations both for the atom and the field.

Comment: Thanks for your response. To be more specific, I am more curious for the semi-classical approach scenario, can you explain more on that? In a context of laser cooling for example.

Comment: In laser cooling you treat the electric field classically. You find the steady state solution from the Bloch equations and get the expressions for the scattering force and the dipole force. The former explains laser cooling, the latter optical trapping.

Comment: I can write down that derivation in my answer if you want, but then you should probably modify your question or ask a new one.

Comment: Right. Those derivations are in Metcalf's Laser cooling and trapping, and these equations describe the evolution of the atom. But as I ask in the title, what are the equations to describe the evolution of the classical laser field?

Comment: The field does not see any back action from the atoms. It evolves purely because of whatever the laser is doing. Because you assume it’s a continuum so there are many photons that a few of them absorbed/emitted do not make a difference.

Comment: I am not convinced but thanks for this answer and I do agree it is an ignorable effect. I do have another possible answer: we can derive the evolution of the expectation of the atom dipole momentum from its density matrix, then solve the classical electric field with Maxwell equations, both emission and absorption should be in that result as phase match and dismatch with laser field. I am not sure about this answer, though.

Comment: You can’t have absorption/emission from the field’s point of view unless you quantise the field, I.e. you write it in terms of creation & annihilation operators. What you are suggesting would just be adding a classical laser field with a classical (atomic) dipole field, and would not be taking into account the dynamical changes of absorption/emission processes.

Comment: Sure. Let me rephrase: this summation field of laser and dipole does not represent the result of any single atomic absorption and emission process, but it should represents the expected value of the field when we treat the atom as the ensemble average of itself, just like what we did to the spontaneous emission when solving the steady state solution of the Bloch equation. Is this statement correct?

Comment: Then that’s basically a steady state/average. I guess yes.